# Dúvida sobre a conexão LDAP + php

Tags: php, openldap

estou criando uma classe para autenticação LDAP para integrar com apps intranet, como gerador de protocolo, etc.

**1-** Após efetuar o `ldap_bind()` e conectar o usuário, existe alguma persistência desta autenticação? Existe a necessidade de encerrá-la com `ldap_close()` quando o usuário sair ou deslogar?

**Bônus:** As vezes, mais de um usuário utiliza o mesmo computador, porém em logins diferentes, como poderia gerenciar estas autenticações para que elas ficassem armazenadas durante determinado período?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo depende. Digo isso porque eu não sei como sua empresa usa o LDAP. Algumas empresas usam o LDAP só como árvore de diretórios onde mantém sua estrutura, colaboradores e alguns atributos de tal como nome, alguns grupos, etc... Usado preferencialmente para logins nas estações de trabalho.

Outras empresas no entanto usam mais profundamente o LDAP gerenciando boa parte de informações dos colaboradores, estruturas hierarquicas complexas da própria empresa, árvore de permissões para acesso a sistemas e áreas restritas da empresa, controle de acesso em catracas e por aí vai. Ou seja, no mercado por aí há usos e mais usos do LDAP.

Dito isso, acho que posso prosseguir com a resposta a sua pergunta.

## Se você for só autenticar o usuário...

Se sua empresa apenas autentica usuários, então você só vai tentar fazer o *bind* no servidor usando usuário e senha de quem quer acessar a aplicação. **Se o servidor LDAP recusar o bind**, o usuário e senha estão errados e você informa o usuário sobre o falha na autenticação, fecha a conexão e um abraço.

## Se você for autenticar e recuperar algumas propriedades do usuário...

Bom, se sua empresa guarda algumas informações do usuário no LDAP, como matrícula, líder (ou gerente), telefone... Você pode recuperar essas informações do LDAP e mostrar no seu sistema. Então aí você precisará saber um pouco sobre a sintaxe de busca de LDAP.

Com informações recuperadas do LDAP, você também pode integrar sua aplicação com outros sistemas (se possível) como RH, ERP e por aí vai.

Nessa caso, você faz o bind, recupera a informação, salva essa informação em sessão (ou persiste) e então você pode fechar a conexão com ldap.

## Se você precisar recuperar permissões de acesso...

Nessa caso, depende do seu sistema. Se você precisará recuperar papel e permissão do LDAP para cada usuário que acessa sua aplicação e verifica se esse usuário pode ou não acessar determinada funcionalidade do seu sistema, você aqui, até poderia manter a conexão aberta com o LDAP e fecha-la após o usuário fazer o logout.

Aqui, suas consultas ap LDAP poderão ser mais frequentes, por isso voce poderia manter a conexão aberta se não quiser salvar as permissões do usuário na sessão.

## Respondendo diretamente suas perguntas

> Após efetuar o ldap_bind() e conectar o usuário, existe alguma
>   persistência desta autenticação? Existe a necessidade de encerrá-la
>   com ldap_close() quando o usuário sair ou deslogar?

Eu só trabalhei com o AD (active Directory) da Microsoft. E nesse caso eu não vi ele persistindo nada lá quando fazemos bind nele em nossas aplicações. Todo esse controle é feito internamente na minha aplicação. Para nós, o LDAP é apenas um flag de login com sucesso true ou false. E também recupero algumas coisas, nada mais que isso.

Mas acredito que seja uma boa prática encerrar a conexão, assim como existe o fechamento de conexão com banco de dados, como streamings...

> As vezes, mais de um usuário utiliza o mesmo computador, porém em
>   logins diferentes, como poderia gerenciar estas autenticações para que
>   elas ficassem armazenadas durante determinado período?

Esse controle é sua aplicação que faz, não o LDAP. Ambos o usuários precisarão digitar usuário e senha na sua aplicação e sua aplicação gerencia o resto. Como disse na resposta acima, o LDAP apenas responderá true ou false para você em uma combinação login e senha. O resto, é por sua conta.

Comment: Ricardo, sanou completamente minhas dúvidas, vou recuperar algumas informações sim, como email, vou aplicar o ldap_read() com filtro, muito obrigado!